# Implementing a loop for a Python Socket Script

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to implement a loop for this socket code, but I can't quite seem to wrap my head around it. Is anyone able to explain it for me?

Here's the code

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 65432        # The port used by the server

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(b'Hello, world')
    data = s.recv(1024)

print('Received', repr(data))
```

Comment: A loop for what purpose?  To just send, recv, and print?  If so, then don't you think send, recv, and print need to be in a loop?  I'm not sure where you are confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you possible mean this?

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 65432        # The port used by the server

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    while True:
        s.sendall(b'Hello, world')
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print('Received', repr(data))
```